# Not able to add settings 'log_queries=1' in clickhouse settings

Tags: clickhouse

I want to see query_logs in my clickhouse database using table 'system.query_log'.

But when i fire the select command, i get the error, table does not exist.Then i checked the settings using below command:

Select * from system.settings where name = 'log_queries' LIMIT 1;
I got the below response:

```
Name         Value       changed         description        min      max         readonly       type

log_queries    0              0          Log request and    NULL     NULL          0            bool
                                         write to system
                                         tables
```

From the clickhouse documentation value column should have '1' as a value.
So i tried the update command and it got failed with below error:
"DB::Exception: Mutations are not supported by storage SystemSettings."

**How do i change this value and make logging possible and where should i do these changes??**

Answer (score 3):

To turn on logging to [system.query_log](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_log/) need to set [log_queries](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#settings-log-queries) in config-file:

1. open exist or create a new custom config file in */etc/clickhouse-server/users.d* folder

```sh
nano /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/users.xml
```

2. set required parameter

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<yandex>
    <profiles>
        <default>
            <log_queries replace="replace">1</log_queries>
        </default>
    </profiles>
</yandex>
```

Comment: Thanks vladimir. I can see in the folder /etc/clickhouse-server there is a file called users.xml and a folder users.d, should i change this file or create another file in users.d?? Also i need to test some other parameter like 'max_server_memory_usage_to_ram_ratio' should i do the change in config.xml directly or these changes are needs to be done in users.xml??Also do i need to restart the server after the changes??

Comment: any files with custom settings **should** be in *users.d* folder - it is important because files located there will **not** be rewritten on CH upgrade

Comment: the same rule applied for storing custom system settings - need to create config-files in folder */etc/clickhouse-server/config.d*

Comment: the *clickhouse-server*-service should be restarted when changed system-settings, not users-settings